# I am trying to take image input in html file and display and i am using flask as a server . but i am not able to display the image

Tags: python, html, flask

After uploading the image and clicking submit ,

it is giving me output as

Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

instead of displaying image

this is my python code

```
import os
from flask import Flask,flash, request,render_template,redirect,url_for,session
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from datetime import timedelta


Upload_path = r'static\images'
allowed_ext = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "helloWorld"
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
app.config[" UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = Upload_path

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session.permanent = True
        if "file" not in request.files:
            flash('no file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash("no selected file")
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
        session['filename'] = filename 
        return redirect(url_for('upload_img1.html'))
    return render_template('upload_img1.html')
        
@app.route("/view_report")
def view_img():
    if "filename" in session:
        
        filename = session['filename']
        print(filename)
        path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)
        return redirect(url_for(path))
    return "hii"


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload your report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload your report</h1>
        <form action = "/view_report", method="POST",enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <p><input type='file', name='file'></p>
            <p><input type='submit',value='upload'></p>
        </form> 
            
        {% if filename %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ url_for(path) }}">
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

After uploading the image and clicking submit , it should display the image at view_report

Comment: In your form you specify `action="/view_report"` and `method="POST"`. That means that when you submit your form, it is trying to make a POST request to `/view_report`. But looking at the route definition of `/view_report`, it doesn't accept POST request; only GET requests (default value).

Comment: okk. I changed it to action = "/" . i also changed in return fucction in to redirect("view_img"). But it is still not displaying image .

Answer (score 0):

(`Method Not Allowed` solved via comment on question)

**Short answer:**

1. Instead of `redirect(url_for('upload_img1.html'))` you should render the html page with the filename as argument instead if you want to show the image:

```py
return render_template('upload_img1.html', filename=filename)
```

2. Remove all the commas between your html attributes. E.g.:

```html
<p><input type='file' name='file'></p>
```

instead of

```html
<p><input type='file', name='file'></p>
```

3. The `img`-tag should look like that:

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + filename) }}">
```

(Eventually needing a `\` instead of `/`)

**Explanations:**

1. Flask cannot build a route endpoint for an html template-file. If you wanna give a rendered template to the user, you have to use `render_template`. And above you can see how to pass variables into the rendering process. Jinja can't take the variables from the python code, you explicitly have to pass them in.
2. It is simply erroneous syntax. Don't do it. Just use spaces as shown above.
3. You can't use random variables (as explained int (1.)). The variable `path` didn't get passed when rendering but can be easily constructed from `filename` as shown above.
   `url_for('static', filename=...)` creates a link to the `static` endpoint which exists to serve static files. `filename=...`  specifies which static file should get delivered.